# Want to show just captured photo instead of live view

Tags: java, android, photo

When I capture a photo from camera, I want to show it instead of live view.
Is there anything wrong with the URI or should I write a return page code?

What I am doing so far:

```java
 public void btnTakePhotoClicked(View v) {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    File pictureDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    String fullPath = "";
    File imageFile = null;
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String pictureName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";

    fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ImageFolder/" + pictureName;

    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ImageFolder/");

    imageFile = new File(fullPath);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean *it flash back*

Comment: haaaa... i mean it colse itself

Comment: @Sarz can u help me solve this

Comment: Right, you can create another form and just swap your view with the photo you have captured. **More** If you see this form contains all gallery images. 1 more question. What you mean by *it no answer and turn off*. Does it exits the application?

Comment: @Sarz yes! exits the application !

Comment: Well it seems, there is some error better check your IDE console to track down the problem

Comment: @Sarz can I add your facebook or whatsapp? I can send u some pic to say my problem if you want :)

Comment: @Sarz Iam new for AS and really have big problem wit it ><...